# PHP Mysql - select * data from a specific Month,Year

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "work");
 

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 

$sql = "SELECT count(`data`) AS `cnt_days`, sum(`ore`) AS `sum_hours`, DATE_FORMAT(`data`,'%M %Y', 'ro_RO') AS `year_month`, sum(`castig`) AS `sum_castig` FROM `rapoarte` WHERE 1 GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `data`) ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `data`) DESC;";


if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo '<br><br><br><table align="center" border="0">';
        echo '<tr>' . '<th height"100%" colspan="5">' . 'Ore Lucrate' . '</th>';   
        echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Month</th>";
                echo "<th>Nr. Tickets/month</th>";
                echo "<th>Nr. Hours Worked</th>";
                echo "<th>$ earned</th>";
                echo "<th>View all tickets for this month</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $luna = $row['year_month'];
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['year_month'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['cnt_days'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['sum_hours'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['sum_castig'] . "€" . "</td>";
                echo '<td>' . '<form type="post" action="">' .'<input type="submit" name="export"/>' . '</form>' . '</td>';
        
                
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} 
else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
        



mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

I have this script that shows me in a table all the values ​​in the mysql table for a month, for example if I have 5 entries in the table for January, it shows me the name of the month and year, it shows me the number of tickets for January, the total amount of hours worked and the amount earned.

I leave here an example of what the generated table looks like.

I don't know how I can do the following:

I want in the column where it says "View all tickets for this month" next to each month that appears to me to have a link / button that will open a new page that shows me all the values ​​in the mysql table for that month (year_month) .

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: The simpliest would be a link with a parameter such as `www.example.com/your_page.php?month=<month number goes there>`

Answer (score 0):

Add link in one of your table rows that display month_and year

```php
 echo "<td>"<a href="/your_page?year_month='.$row['year_month']  . '">' . $row['year_month'] . "</td>"
```

And then you can get month and year like so

```php
$year_month = explode('_', $_GET['year_month']);
$year = $year_month[0];
$month = $month[1];
```

In your SQL Query you can add where condition and use SQL `MONTH` and `YEAR` functions.